# Laravel 5 Register Route with get parameter for registration key

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-5

Trying to allow registration via secret key only.

Want to pass in the key to the view. The new L5 auth system is a little buttoned down, do not want to make changes to vendor files if possible.

E.g. /auth/register/Md5-key-code-here

Register View:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... extend the AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' class getRegister method:

```
public function getRegister($key)
{
    return view('auth.register')
            ->with('key', $key);
}
```